# Questionable Cipher

Tags: cipher

I have received a rather peculiar cipher and in all my years of crypto, I have never seen a cipher like this. The cipher is Numeric, Uppercase mixed with Lowercase. The only hint I'm given is "Capital Letters Mean Something". If this isn't enough info, I'm sorry. The person I received the challenge from hasn't given me any other information.

Ciphertext as follows:
SQr1, IsNp, Nz2SY, rstuy? Io hns LyXL?

Comment: Kinda doesn't help how short the text is.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely won't help.

Comment: One thought though, is an Alberti Cipher. It uses capital letters and numbers to change between two alphabets.